# Is $2x + y \geq k$ a convex set?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, problem-solving

I'm asked to prove that $2x+y \geq k$ is a convex set.

My teacher told me to take two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ within the set.

Then he showed two inequalities:

1. $2 x_1 + y_1 \geq k$
2. $2 x_2 + y_2 \geq k$

After that he multiplied the inequalities by $\lambda$ and $[1-\lambda]$

3. $(2 x_1 + y_1 ) \lambda \geq 6 \lambda$
4. $2 x_2 + y_2 [1-\lambda] \geq 6[1- \lambda]$

And he ended up with this expression:
$2 x_1 \lambda +2 x_2 [1-\lambda]+ y_1 \lambda + y_2 [1-\lambda] \geq k$ to finally proof the set is convex.

My doubt is how he manage to get from $3$ and $4$ to the last expression. Thanks to anyone who take the time to help me.

Comment: $2x+y \geq k$ is not a set, it is an inequality.

Comment: 4) is not derived from 3), it is derived from 2) instead. If, that is, you fix the error with the numeral 6.

Comment: Is there a typo on the right hand side of 3) and 4)? On the right hand side of 1) and 2) you have $k$, so multiplying by $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$ should give you $k\lambda$ and $k(1-\lambda)$ right?

Comment: If that's the case, then the last inequality is obtained by adding 3) and 4) together.

Comment: In fact, the left hand side of 4) doesn't look quite right either. It seems to be missing a pair of parentheses. According to your description of the process, 4) should be $(2x_2+y_2)(1-\lambda)\geq k(1-\lambda)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x, y) = 2x + y$, since $f$ is linear it is both concave and convex. The set $\{(x, y) : 2x + y \geq k\} = \{(x, y): f(x, y) \geq k\}$ is a superlevel set of $f$. Since $f$ is concave, this set is convex.